# Get variable from rewrite url in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

In my conf file I have this rule:

```
rewrite ^/signup /register.php;
rewrite ^/signup/([0-9A-Z]+)$ /register.php?ref=$1;
```

When access site.com/signup all is work
And now in my php file, I have

```
if(isset($_GET['ref'])) {
$ref = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['ref']); 
}
```

When I try to get variable ref from this url site.com/signup/abc123 show nothing!
Is something in rewrite rule?

Comment: [0-9A-Z]  only uppercase and matching fails. Change rule
`rewrite ^/signup/([0-9A-Za-z]+)$ /register.php?ref=$1;`

Comment: Not work, not show ref

Comment: Add rule my conf, I do request `http://homedomain/signup/abc123` get an response `Array ( [ref] => abc123 )`

Comment: I understood, the first rule only works.

Comment: Change rule `rewrite ^/signup[/]*([0-9A-Za-z]*)$ /register.php?ref=$1;`  and delete first rule `rewrite ^/signup /register.php;`

Comment: Then always set ref, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
 if ( $uri ~ "^/signup$" ) {
 rewrite (.*)  /register.php;
}
if ( $uri ~ "^/signup/([0-9A-Za-z]*)$" ) {
  rewrite ^/signup/([0-9A-Za-z]*)$ /register.php?ref=$1;
}
```

Comment: So complicated istead of just changing order of directives. Rewrites apply in order of appearance. If rewrite doesn't match it's just skipped.